# UIButton and UIView that have the same frame: how to access one or the other dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

**Here is my issue:** I have a transparent `UIBUtton` hooked up to an action with a control event `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat`. Behind this `UIButton` I have a `UIView` with the exact same frame as my `UIButton`, that has a `UIGestureRecognizer`added to it.

**My question is:** Since both views have the same frame, is there a way to dynamically access one or the other depending on the user interaction.

- i.e:

  If the user double tap on the button, the button will be accessed, other wise, if no `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` is detected, the view behind it will be accessed.

Any ideas on how to proceed ?
Thanks guys

Comment: Why are you using an UIButton AND an UIView? You could use just the View and gesture recognizers for one tap and two taps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 2 `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view without a button and achieve what you are looking for.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let doubleTapGest:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onTappedTwice")
    doubleTapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    let singleTapGest:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onTapped")
    singleTapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    singleTapGest.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(doubleTapGest)

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGest)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGest)
}

func onTapped() {
    NSLog("Tapped once")
}

func onTappedTwice() {
    NSLog("Tapped twice")
}
```